# how to reverse word using java by using hasprevious() method?

Tags: java, arrays

```
      ArrayList<String> aList = new ArrayList<String>();

        //Add elements to ArrayList object
        aList.add("1");
      aList.add("2");
       aList.add("3");
        aList.add("4");
        aList.add("5");

        //Get an object of ListIterator using listIterator() method
        ListIterator listIterator = aList.listIterator();

        //Traverse in forward direction  
        System.out.println("Traversing ArrayList in forward directio using ListIterator");
        while(listIterator.hasNext())
          System.out.println(listIterator.next());

        /*
          Traverse the ArrayList in reverse direction using hasPrevious and previous
          methods of ListIterator. hasPrevious method returns true if
          ListIterator has more elements to traverse in reverse direction.
          Previous method returns previous element in the list.
        */
        System.out.println("Traversing ArrayList in reverse direction using ListIterator");
        while(listIterator.hasPrevious())
          System.out.println(listIterator.previous());

      }
    }
```

In the above code list of array value is printed in reverse. But I need to reverse the single array sentence using the same method.
Ex: aList.add("hello world"); here only one string is there. but need to reverse the word like "world hello".

Comment: Split on whitespace, traverse the resulting array in reverse order.

Answer (score 4):

You could `split` the `String` into an array of `String`(s), convert that to a `List<String>` with `Arrays.asList` and then `reverse` that. Something like,

```
String str = "hello world";
List<String> al = Arrays.asList(str.split("\\s+"));
Collections.reverse(al);
for (String s : al) {
    System.out.print(s + " ");
}
System.out.println();
```

Output is (as requested)

```
world hello
```

**Alternatively**, modify your `ListIterator` (and you shouldn't use [*raw types*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html)). Something like,

```
String str = "hello world";
List<String> al = Arrays.asList(str.split("\\s+"));
ListIterator<String> listIterator = al.listIterator();
```

And I get

```
Traversing ArrayList in forward directio using ListIterator
hello
world
Traversing ArrayList in reverse direction using ListIterator
world
hello
```